# How do I use stylus-resources-loader with Vue CLI 3?

Tags: vue.js, stylus, vue-cli

I know that it involves modifying `vue.config.js`, but simply pasting my desired config in the `configureWebpack` object doesn't seem to work. Has anyone else been able to figure this out?

Desired config to add:

```
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "vue-loader",
                            options: {
                                loaders: {
                                    stylus: [
                                        {
                                            loader: "stylus-resources-loader",
                                            options: {
                                                resources:
                                                    "./src/assets/_base.styl",
                                            },
                                        },
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap((options) => {
        options.loaders.stylus = options.loaders.stylus.concat({
          loader: 'stylus-resources-loader',
          options: {
            resources: path.resolve('./src/assets/_base.styl'),
          },
        });
        return options;
      });
  },
};
```

---

*UPDATE:*

It should be noted that the value of the `lang` attribute in `<style lang="stylus">` will affect the way the configuration item is written!
When `lang` is `stylus`, the `stylus` are mounted on `loader`, which should be written like this: `options.loaders.stylus`, and when the value of `lang` is `styl`, It should be written as `options.loaders.styl`.

Because of the following code in [`@vue/cli-service/lib/webpack/CSSLoaderResolver.js`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/webpack/CSSLoaderResolver.js#L114-L120):

```js
getLoader (test, loader, options = {}) {
  styl (test = /\.styl$/) {
    return this.getLoader(test, 'stylus')
  }

  stylus (test = /\.stylus$/) {
    return this.getLoader(test, 'stylus')
  }
}
```

refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49086022/4723163

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I'm also using Typescript on this project, would that make any difference?

Comment: Sorry, this is my fault. Please change `options.loaders.styl` to `options.loaders.stylus`, it should be able to work properly.