# Using sass-resources-loader with vue-cli v3.x

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

How to use [sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader) with vue-cli@3.x to add global scss variables and mixins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vue-cli@3.x uses [webpack-chain](https://github.com/mozilla-neutrino/webpack-chain) to manage its webpack config. To add sass-resources-loader to the predefined webpack config. Add the following to the `vue.config.js`

**vue.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap((options) => {
        options.loaders.scss = options.loaders.scss.concat({
          loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
          options: {
            resources: path.resolve('./src/scss/_variables.scss'),
          },
        })
        return options
      })

    config
      .module
      .rule('scss')
      .use('sass-resources-loader')
      .loader('sass-resources-loader')
      .options({
        resources: path.resolve('./src/scss/_variables.scss'),
      })
  },
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: in my case vue-loader options contains just {compilerOptions: { preserveWhitespace: false }}

which leads to TypeError: Cannot read property 'scss' of undefined
Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any longer with vue-loader 15.

Answer (score 11):

As you can see in [the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders), the easiest way is to use loaderOptions for the sass preprocessor. No need for any extra dependency:

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `
          @import "@/scss/_variables.scss";
          @import "@/scss/_mixins.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: As @constant-meiring mentioned before, this is the right way solve this using vue-loader 15

Answer (score 0):

```
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
        stylus: {
            loader: 'stylus-resources-loader',
            import: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/styles/imports.styl')]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.