# Vue CLI 3 sass-resources-loader - Options.loaders undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I was able to successfully configure a new Vue project using the 3.0 version of the CLI to use `sass-resource-loader` a few weeks ago using the information posted here: [Using sass-resources-loader with vue-cli v3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49086021/using-sass-resources-loader-with-vue-cli-v3-x/50492650#50492650)

However, after updating everything today I'm encountering the following error when running `npm run serve`:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'scss' of undefined`

the only options that seem to be getting passed into `.tap(options)` are:

`{ compilerOptions: { preserveWhitespace: false } }`

I don't currently know enough about `chainWebpack` to effectively debug, but I'm working on it. If anyone has any insights into what's changed to cause this error, it'd be greatly appreciated.

my `vue.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap((options) => {
        console.log(options)
        options.loaders.scss = options.loaders.scss.concat({
          loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
          options: {
            resources: [
              path.resolve('./src/scss/_variables.scss'),
              path.resolve('./src/scss/_mixins.scss')
            ]
          },
        })
        return options
      })
    config
      .module
      .rule('scss')
      .use('sass-resources-loader')
      .loader('sass-resources-loader')
      .options({
        resources: [
          path.resolve('./src/scss/_variables.scss'),
          path.resolve('./src/scss/_mixins.scss')
        ]
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of tapping into webpack chain can you just use the css loader option specified in the Vue CLI docs at the bottom of this page https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/css.md

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `vue-cli@3.x`, this probably means that your project uses `vue-loader@15.x`
[Since version 15](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/migrating.html#loader-inference), the `vue-loader` does not need additional configs for loaders.
You can configure only your main webpack loaders.

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .module
      .rule('scss')
      .use('sass-resources-loader')
      .loader('sass-resources-loader')
      .options({
        resources: [
          path.resolve('./src/scss/_variables.scss'),
          path.resolve('./src/scss/_mixins.scss')
        ]
      })
  }
}
```

> You can also inspect webpack configs using the `vue inspect` or `./node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service inspect` commands.

Comment: I tried your solution but I get this: `Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
        ^
      Undefined variable: "$brand-color".
      in C:\dev\git\vue-typescript-test\src\components\HelloWorld.vue (line 60, column 10)` This is on a fresh VueCli project

Comment: Have the same issue as @ConstantinChirila

Comment: @Victor i managed to do it without the sass-resource-loader. In your `vue.config.js` add this: 
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/scss/_config.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
} You can check more in here:  https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors

Comment: Updating last @ConstantinChirila comment :
You should now use "prependData" instead of "data" which is deprecated now (sass-loader v8)

Comment: This solution will reimport _config.scss in every lang="scss" style you define.  (your resulting bundle will have multiple duplicated style tags).  not an optimal solution