# How to load a _variables.scss file for all Vue components using sass-resource-loader on Vue CLI 3.04?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, vuejs2

I have a fresh VueJs project scaffold using the Vue CLI 3.0.4
I want to use SCSS variables inside all the components without having to import the `_variables.scss` in all the components. 
I want to import `_variables.scss` and I found that can be done by using sass-resource-loader. 
I've looked at all the answers around here and all are outdated as they do not work with vue-loader 15.

So inside `vue.config.js` i have the following:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('sass')
      .use('sass-resources-loader')
      .loader('sass-resources-loader')
      .options({
        resources: [
          path.resolve('./src/scss/config/_variables.scss'),
        ]
      })
  }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

undefined
        ^
      Undefined variable: "$brand-color".
      in C:\dev\git\vue-typescript-test\src\components\HelloWorld.vue (line 60, column 10)
```

The $brand-color variable is used in the Helloworld.vue component so it seams the variables are not added.

I can't seem to understand why it does not work, as i followed the docs in the Vue CLI by the letter.

Also I want to point out that I followed the chosen answer here: [Vue CLI 3 sass-resources-loader - Options.loaders undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492833/vue-cli-3-sass-resources-loader-options-loaders-undefined)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work using this following code snippet.

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `@import "@/scss/config/_variables.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

> Note that @ is a shortcut to access the src folder.

---

Don't forget to install `node-sass` and `sass-loader` as well.

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader
```

Finally, add the `lang` attribute to your `style` tags.

```
<style lang="scss">

// some style...

</style>
```

Comment: The solution did solve my issue without the sass-resource-loader, which is even better! I've missed this part of the documentation for anyone interested: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules

Comment: You should now use "prependData" instead of "data" which is deprecated now (sass-loader v8)

Comment: for sass-loader 8+ use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60877091/3523778