# Sass-loader error 'options has an unknown property 'indentedSyntax'' when upgrading Vuetify from 1.5 to 2

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

I am upgrading Vuetify in my Vue CLI 3 project from version 1.5 to 2. I have followed [these](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/releases-and-migrations) instructions, doing a full install. Since the upgrade, running 'npm run serve' gives me a ton of errors looking like this:

```
error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/src/components/VGrid/_grid.sass

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialised using an options object that does not match the API schema.
     - options has an unknown property 'indentedSyntax'. These properties are valid:
       object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }
        at validate (C:\Users\kristoffer.dahl\Documents\Prosjekter\fridgein\fridgein_fe\node_modules\sass-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:50:11)
        at Object.loader (C:\Users\kristoffer.dahl\Documents\Prosjekter\fridgein\fridgein_fe\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\index.js:36:28)
```

All errors look the same, except for the Vuetify component mentioned.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "fridgein_fe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.22",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.10.2",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.7",
    "@vue/cli": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-shared-utils": "^3.11.0",
    "auth0-js": "^9.11.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-float-action-button": "^0.4.4",
    "vue-google-charts": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-plugin-load-script": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4",
    "webstomp-client": "^1.2.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "deepmerge": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "fibers": "^4.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.23.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.41.0"
  },
```

This is my `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
          data: `@import "~@/sass/main.scss"`
        },
      },
    },
}
```

I have checked out and tried every solution presented in relevant issues on the developers' Github pages, but none has has any effect.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it by downgrading `sass-loader` by setting

```
"sass-loader": "7.3.1",
```

in `package.json`.

This was suggested on the Vuetify Discord

Comment: This was it, thank you. I had previously tried 7.0.0, but 7.3.1 did the trick.

Comment: Hi! You don't need to downgrade `sass-loader`. Just use the new property `prependData` instead of `data`.  
Check this [Github Issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/760#issuecomment-534043880)

Answer (score 18):

Actually you are using sass-loader 8+ and it has an option a little bit different.
Try using `prependData` instead of `data`.
Check this [github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/760#issuecomment-534043880)

```js
module.exports = {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sass: {
          prependData: `@import "~@/sass/main.scss"`
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to add ; at the end for it to work like this: prependData: `@import "~@/sass/main.scss";` 

Otherwise great solution.

Comment: Great @Perp. I just used String Template in case somebody add more `@import`.

Comment: How do I do this with nuxt?

Comment: Please note https://stackoverflow.com/a/64231359/414385

Answer (score 14):

Update for those using version 10+. `prependData` is no longer valid. However you can use `additionalData` as a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 6):

Using the webpack 5.1.3 and sass-loader version 10.0.3, I had to use a different syntax (***additionalData*** instead of ***prependData***), as bellow:

**webpack.config.js**

```js
        {
          test: /\.(css|scss|sass|less)$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader',
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader',
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                additionalData: '@import "assets/scss/_variables.scss";'
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
```

Bear in mind the syntax requires the double quotes in the path and the semicolon before the end of the single quote just as if you were writing a normal scss file.

**Example:**

```js
'@import "path/_file.scss";'
```

In case you need to import multiple files you can use the template string symbol (``) as bellow:

```js
        {
          test: /\.(css|scss|sass|less)$/,
          use: [
            ...
            {
              ...
              options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                additionalData: `@import "assets/scss/_variables.scss";
                                 @import "assets/scss/_mixins.scss";
                                 @import "assets/scss/_misc.scss";`
                },
              },
            },
          ],
        },
```

You can also take the advantage of template string as bellow:

```js
`@import "${path.resolve(APP_DIR, '/assets/scss/')}/_variables.scss";`
```

**Be advised**: I tried this approach to reduce bundle size and the result was terrible as when you start to see what the webpack is actually doing you return to the basic ***import all needed styles in your main component as sass-loader will actually prepend in multiple components the styles you inform in the additional data.*** In my case the bundle got 3 times it's original size.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you use NUXT you should configure like this：

```
//nuxt.config.js
loaders: {
  less: {
    lessOptions: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      modifyVars: {
        'primary-color': '#5c6ac4',
        'layout-body-background': '#fff'
      }
    }
  }
}
```