# Import Global SASS variables into VUEPRESS components

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuepress

In **Vuepress**, is there a way to globally import a `.sass` file with my variables so I don't need to importing it everytime I use a variable?

Maybe something like we do in VUE:

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        data: `
          @import "@/sass/_variables.sass";
          @import "@/sass/_mixins.sass";
        `
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @michal-levý pointed about using alias, I just figured out that I can use vuepress builtin alias `@theme`. So my `config.js` is like.

```js
module.exports = {
  sass: {
    data: '@import "@theme/styles/_variables"'
  }
}
```

Worked Fine!

I'm using `.sass` sintax and `sass-loader - 7.3.1` [due another bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59969138/2711450), so that's why I used `data` instead of `prependData`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [you can do that](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#sass)....

```js
// .vuepress/config.js
module.exports = {
  sass: {
    prependData: `
        @import "@/sass/_variables.sass";
        @import "@/sass/_mixins.sass";
      `
  }
};
```

Use `prependData` for `sass-loader` v8+ or `data` if you are using older `sass-loader`

### Update

Tried it myself. I'v had problem with `@` alias not resolving so a created my own alias - in this case for `.vuepress/styles` directory

```js
// .vuepress/config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  sass: {
    prependData: `
        @import "@styles/_variables.sass";
      `
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "@styles": path.resolve(__dirname, "./styles")
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/import-global-sass-variables-into-vuepress-components-8m58x) ....after it starts, navigate to Guide

If you change `prependData` to `data`, change `sass-loader` version to 7.3.1 (fr example) and restart the sandbox, it also works...

Comment: Thanks @michal-levý but it didn't work. I'm using and older `sass-loader` version due another bug. I still have to import sass files in every component to access the variables. I'd appreciatte if you have another idea. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot @michal-levý. As a matter of fact your solution gimme some light into the alias 'problem'. I realised that I can use the `@theme` alias, so I did and worked fine! Thanks for your time to help me on this and point me in the right direction!
I'm posting the answer that worked for me, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share my solution, maybe it will work for somebody. Assuming your project has structure like this:

```
your-project/
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── src/
└── docs/
    ├── .vuepress
    │   ├── components/*.vue
    │   ├── styles/main.scss
    │   ├── config.js
    │   └── enhanceApp.js
    └── README.md
```

Add the following code into `config.js`

```js
// config.js

const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    sassOptions: { indentedSyntax: true },
    alias: {
        'styles': path.resolve(__dirname, './styles')
    },
    scss: {
        additionalData: `
            @import "~styles/main.scss";
        `
    }
}
```

Worked for me as a charm